# Inherit or set permissions for all new files under a specific path

Tags: linux, access-control-list

I would like the Linux filing system to set a specific group when new files and directories are created by different users under a specific directory.  I know I can use chown to change existing files and directories but I want it to happen automatically.  Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard user/group/other security model in Unix doesn't support this.  The closest you can get are the "sticky" bits to assign ownership and group to newly created files.

However, you tagged this `acl`, and that might open the door: you can set a default ACL that will be inherited down the tree; see the `-d` switch to [setfacl(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl), and the details under "automatically created entries" in the same manual page to understand how that works.

http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/linux-acl.html#default has further examples of how to use these tools.

If all you needed to do was make sure new things got created with a specific directory, though, that is much easier:

```
chgrp some-group /path/to/directory
chmod g+s /path/to/directory
```

That has no influence over file mode, just file ownership.

Comment: Wouldn't the sticky bit for the group solve his needs?

Comment: @jjmontes - I don't believe so, since he talks about *chmod* rather than chown.  Rereading, though, it could be that was a typo for chown, and the sticky bit would solve the problem.  That would be `chmod g+s /path/to/directory`

Comment: @Daniel Pitteman:Sorry I did mean chown not chmod :)

Comment: Then @jjmontes was on the money.  Use the sticky bit on the directory to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: Yes the ACL stuff worked.  I used this specific command: setfacl -R -m d:u::rwx,d:g:homework:rwx,o::- /home/Homework

Comment: @Daniel, just reviewing old questions, yes I see it is chown not chmod not sure why I put the wrong one...  Anyway I will change the question.